# connection error while sending api call to mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, express, mern

//server connection file

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const UserModel = require('./models/Users')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/crud")

app.get("/",(req,res) => {
   UserModel.Find({})
   .then(users => res.json(users))
   .catch(err => res.json(err))
})

app.get("/getUser/:id", (req,res) => {
   const id = req.params.id;
   UserModel.FindById({_id:id})
   .then(users => res.json(users))
   .catch(err => res.json(err))
})

app.put("/updateUser/:id", (req,res) => {
   const id = req.params.id;
   UserModel.FindByIdAndUpdate({_id:id}, {
      name: req.body.name, 
      email: req.body.email, 
      age:req.body.age})
   .then(users => res.json(users))
   .catch(err => res.json(err))
})

app.delete("/deleteUser/:id", (req, res) => {
   const id = req.params.id;
   UserModel.FindByIdAndDelete({_id:id})
   .then(users => res.json(users))
   .catch(err => req.json( err))
})

app.post("/createUser", (req, res) => {
   UserModel.create(req.body)
   .then(users => res.json(users))
   .catch(err => req.json( err))
})


app.listen(3001, () => {
   console.log("Server is running.")
})
```

//package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

//ui to render user list

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import axios from 'axios'

function Users () {
   const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
      axios.get("http://localhost:3001")
      .then(result => setUsers(result.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
   },[])

   const handleDelete = (id) => {
      axios.delete("http://localhost:3001/deleteUser/"+id)
      .then(result => {console.log(result)
         window.location.reload()})
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
   }

   return (
       <div className="d-flex vh-100 bg-primary justify-content-center align-items-center">
             <div className='w-50 bg-white rounded p-3'>
                 <Link to="/create" className="btn btn-success"> Add</Link>
                 <table className='table'>
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                                 <th>Name</th>
                                 <th>Email</th>
                                 <th>Age</th>
                                 <th>Action</th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                       {
                           users.map((user) => {
                           return <tr>
                              <td>{user.name}</td>
                              <td>{user.email}</td>
                              <td>{user.age}</td>
                              <td>
                                 <Link to={`/update/${user._id}`} className="btn btn-warning">Update</Link>
                                 <button className="btn btn-danger" 
                                 onClick={(e) => handleDelete(user._id)}>Delete</button>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           })
                        }
                       </tbody>
                 </table>
             </div>
         </div>
      )
   }

export default Users;
```

//Error:
AxiosError
code
:
"ERR_NETWORK"
config
:
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
:
"Network Error"
name
:
"AxiosError"
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
stack
:
"AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=aae4a243:1447:14)"
[[Prototype]]
:
Error

it gives error on all api calls including get request to render the users.
to start the app i use:

```
PS E:\Office\React projects\CRUDConnectionIssue\client> npm run dev

> client@0.0.0 dev
> vite


  VITE v4.4.7  ready in 8237 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
```